# Unity Color Matching Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matching

I have searched the similar games on forum and google but i could not find exactly.

I am making a puzzle game. and user can get point if the nodes (horizontal sticks) are same color then he can get.

when they are in same direction it says colors matched but in generated node whenever i rotate the sticks it says also same.

Can you take a look? and tell me how to fix. Also if you have better idea about this matching I will be appreciated.

[image: same direction]   ---------    [image]

```
void Update()
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

        clickTime = Time.time;
        rayhit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, selectableObjLayerMask);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if (rayhit)
        {
            if (Time.time - clickTime < .2f)
            {
                Node node = rayhit.transform.GetComponent<Node>();
                if (node != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < node.sticks.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Vector3 newAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, (node.sticks[i].transform.localEulerAngles.z - 45));
                        newAngles.z = newAngles.z < 0 ? newAngles.z + 180 : newAngles.z;
                        newAngles.z = newAngles.z >180 ? newAngles.z - 180 : newAngles.z;
                        node.sticks[i].transform.localEulerAngles = newAngles;

                        node.sticks[i].degree = (int)newAngles.z;
```

//******** HERE IS COLOR MATCHING*******

```
                        if (node.transform.parent.name=="Node1" && node.sticks[i].degree == 90)
                        {
                            colorMatch[1] = node.sticks[i].color;
                            Debug.Log("COLOR 1___"+ colorMatch[1]);
                            //Debug.Log(colorMatch1);

                        }
                        if (node.transform.parent.name == "Node2" && node.sticks[i].degree == 90)
                        {
                            colorMatch[2] = node.sticks[i].color;
                            Debug.Log("COLOR 2___" + colorMatch[2]);

                        }
                        if (node.transform.parent.name == "Node3" && node.sticks[i].degree == 90)
                        {
                            colorMatch[3] = node.sticks[i].color;
                            Debug.Log("COLOR 3___" + colorMatch[3]);
                            //if (colorMatch[1] == colorMatch[2] && colorMatch[2] == colorMatch[3])
                            //{
                            //    Debug.Log("COLORS MATCHED : " + colorMatch[1]);
                            //}
                        }

                        if (colorMatch[1]==colorMatch[2] && colorMatch[2]==colorMatch[3])
                        {
                            Debug.Log("COLOR MATCHED");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Node currNode = rayhit.transform.GetComponent<Node>();
                if(currNode.isMoved == false)
                {
                    smallestId = 0;
                    smallestDistance = 999;
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
                    {

                        float distance = Vector2.Distance(rayhit.transform.position, nodes[i].transform.position);
                        if (smallestDistance > distance)
                        {
                            smallestDistance = distance;
                            smallestId = i;
                        }

                    }

                    rayhit.transform.position = nodes[smallestId].transform.position;
                    if (rayhit.transform.parent != nodes[smallestId].transform)
                    { 
                        if (nodes[smallestId].transform.childCount > 0 && nodes[smallestId].transform != rayhit.transform.parent)
                        {
                            if (currNode != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < currNode.sticks.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Node>().sticks.Add(currNode.sticks[i]);
                                    currNode.sticks[i].transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0));
                                }
                                Destroy(rayhit.transform.gameObject);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (currNode != null)
                            {
                                currNode.isMoved = true;
                            }
                            rayhit.transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }               

        }
        rayhit = new RaycastHit2D();

    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if(rayhit.transform != null)
        {
            Node currNode = rayhit.transform.GetComponent<Node>();
            if(currNode != null)
                if (currNode.isMoved == false)
                {
                    if (Time.time - clickTime >= 0.2f)
                    {
                        Vector2 newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                        rayhit.transform.position = newPos;
                    }
                }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (node.transform.parent.name=="Node1" && node.sticks[i].degree == 90)
                        {
                            colorMatch[1] = node.sticks[i].color;
                            Debug.Log("COLOR 1___"+ colorMatch[1]);
                            //Debug.Log(colorMatch1);

                        }
                        if (node.transform.parent.name == "Node2" && node.sticks[i].degree == 90)
                        {
                            colorMatch[2] = node.sticks[i].color;
                            Debug.Log("COLOR 2___" + colorMatch[2]);

                        }
                        if (node.transform.parent.name == "Node3" && node.sticks[i].degree == 90)
                        {
                            colorMatch[3] = node.sticks[i].color;
                            Debug.Log("COLOR 3___" + colorMatch[3]);
                            if (colorMatch[1] == colorMatch[2] && colorMatch[2] == colorMatch[3])
                            {
                                Debug.Log("COLORS MATCHED : " + colorMatch[1]);

                            }

                        }
```

Here is working code. but how i can destroy the matched sticks?